# Python metaclass default attributes

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm trying to create metaclass in Python (2.7) that will set arguments passed to object's `__init__` as object attributes.

```
class AttributeInitType(type):        
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(AttributeInitType, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(obj, k, v)
        return obj
```

Usage:

```
class Human(object):
    __metaclass__ = AttributeInitType

    def __init__(self, height=160, age=0, eyes="brown", sex="male"):
        pass

man = Human()
```

**Question:** I want `man` instance to have defaults attributes set as in class's `__init__`. How can I do it?

**Update:** I've came to even better solution that:

- inspects `__init__` method only once during class creation
- does not override attributes that where (possibly) set by class's real `__init__`

Here is the code:

```
import inspect
import copy

class AttributeInitType(type):
    """Converts keyword attributes of the init to object attributes"""
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, d):
        # Cache __init__ defaults on a class-level
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(d["__init__"])
        init_defaults = dict(zip(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults))
        cls = super(AttributeInitType, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, d)
        cls.__init_defaults = init_defaults
        return cls

    def __call__(mcs, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(AttributeInitType, mcs).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        the_kwargs = copy.copy(obj.__class__.__init_defaults)
        the_kwargs.update(kwargs)
        for k, v in the_kwargs.items():
            # Don't override attributes set by real __init__
            if not hasattr(obj, k):
                setattr(obj, k, v)
        return obj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to introspect the `__init__` method and extract any default values from there. The [`getargspec` function](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) would be helpful there.

The `getargspec` function returns (among others) a list of argument names, and a list of default values. You can combine these to find the default argument specification of a given function, then use that information to set attributes on the object:

```
import inspect

class AttributeInitType(type):        
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(AttributeInitType, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(obj.__init__)
        defaults = dict(zip(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults))
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        for key, val in defaults.items():
            setattr(obj, key, val)
        return obj
```

With the above metaclass you can omit any of the arguments and they'll be set on the new instance, or you can override them by passing them in explicitly:

```
>>> man = Human()
>>> man.age
0
>>> man.height
160
>>> Human(height=180).height
180
```

Comment: @ZaarHai: If you have any positional arguments, they'd add to the `args` list, but not to the `defaults` tuple.

Comment: I see. Thanks. It would be great if you could add that note to the answer.

Comment: @ZaarHai: I linked to the argspec documentation, which details this.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation works if you pass the arguments at object creation

```
>>> man
<test.Human object at 0x10a71e810>
>>> dir(man)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> man=Human(height=10)
>>> dir(man)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'height']
>>> man.height
10
```

but it does not work with default arguments. For that, you have to specifically extract them from the `__init__` function object.

An alternative is to decorate the `__init__` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my framework with *args/**kwargs, a class defaults dictionary, and a call to attribute_setter in my base objects **init**. I feel like this is simpler then decoration and definitely less complicated then metaclasses.

```
Class Base(object):
    defaults = {"default_attribute" : "default_value"}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.attribute_setter(self.defaults.items(), *args, **kwargs)

    def attribute_setter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args: # also allow tuples of name/value pairs
            for attribute_name, attribute_value in args:
                setattr(self, attribute_name, attribute_value)
        [setattr(self, name, value) for name, value in kwargs.items()]
b = Base(testing=True)
# print b.testing
# True
# print b.default_attribute
# "default_value"
```

this combination allows the assignment of arbitrary attributes through **init** at runtime by specifying them as keyword arguments (or as positional argument tuples of name/value pairs).

the class defaults dictionary is used to supply default arguments instead of explicitly named keyword arguments in **init**'s argument list. this makes the default attributes that new instances will be created with modifiable at runtime. You can "inherit" class dictionaries via dict.copy + dict.update.